# Halcon.NET region loses data / Region is cropped unintentionally

Tags: region, halcon

I encountered strange behaviour in Halcon.NET that I am trying to understand.

I have ~100 regions and I want to merge the ones that overlap.
To merge the regions I use `Union1()` and then `Connection()` to separate non-overlapping ones.

But in the resulting region there are a lot of regions missing. After some troubleshooting I noticed that only the regions that would fit in the standard 512*512 graphics window would be in the result regions, but this is Halcon.NET so I dont have a graphics window.

If I use the line: `HOP.GenImageConst(out HO unusedImage, "byte", 1200, 1000);` first, everything works fine. The generated empty image is not used in any way in the application.

So this loses data:

```cs
HOperatorSet.Union1(Regions_eroded, out HO Regions_unified)
HOperatorSet.Connection(Regions_unified, out HO Regions_connected);
```

And this doesnt:

```cs
HOperatorSet.GenImageConst(out HO unusedImage, "byte", 1200, 1000); // creating unused image
HOperatorSet.Union1(Regions_eroded, out HO Regions_unified)
HOperatorSet.Connection(Regions_unified, out HO Regions_connected);
```

Is this a bug, am I doing something wrong, or is this how it's supposed to be for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default window size for region creation is 512x512 in Halcon.
To work around this, you can simply turn off region clipping outside of this window with:

```
set_system ('clip_region', 'false')
```

Or in C#:

```
HSystem.SetSystem("clip_region", "false");
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Why on earth would this be default `True` for Halcon.NET?

Comment: To avoid possible memory issue because of hidden region, I think.